# unable to click button while updating current location

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

As fetching current location requires much time so i want to add cancel button. But i'm unable to click any button until it gets the current location. Any suggestions???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run things on the main thread it, can lock everything up - try getting the location using

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(mySelector:) withObject:objectName];
```

UPDATE:

You will need to make an autorelease pool for this new thread too, so as the first line in mySelector, put:

```
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

and at the last line, put:

```
[pool release];
```

All of your other code goes in between. If you don't do this, then you'll get nasty memory problems.

Comment: @Smriti, You are very welcome! Note that you will need to make an auto release pool for this thread. I'll update my answer with this.

Comment: Hey after implementing code all the buttons have started working but not getting current location.                                                           [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getLoc) withObject:nil];                                                    - (void)getLoc
{
 NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
 lm.delegate = self;
 lm.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
 lm.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
 [lm startUpdatingLocation];
 [pool release];
}